# Printing Unicode characters using Java in eclipse works, but not when I export to a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, utf-8

I have code that creates a PrintWriter and prints Unicode symbols

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
out.print("\u2588");
out.close();
```

It works perfectly while saved with UTF-8 encoding inside eclipse, but when I export it to a jar it just prints off question marks.  How would I tell it to use UTF-8 when printing off strings?

Comment: Where are you running your jar?

Comment: From my desktop - Luiggi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse may be helping you to create UTF-8 encoded file but it is better to use the right encoding in your code as well.

FileWriter does not take any parameter for encoding. You can use OutputStreamWriter as it accepts the encoding also. You may change your PrintWriter initialization to:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"),"UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of FileWriter, create a FileOutputStream. then wrap this in an OutputStreamWriter, It allows you to pass an encoding in the constructor.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8")
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(osw);
```